# Unable to install mcrypt on CentOS 6.7 php 5.5.31

Tags: vps, centos6, mcrypt, php-5.5

I am trying to install mcrypt module on my VPS with CentOS 6.7 64bit running php 5.5.31. I tried below things but No package found error is displayed.

```
yum install php-mcrypt
```

I am not sure if this will work for the OS and php version I have on my VPS. I also tried rpm installs following other references after googling it but none of them worked.

Comment: Try this tutorial http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/install-nginx-php-fpm-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/ I use it in centos 6.7 you need to pass repo name where you got php 5.5 from because centos provide php 5.3 only

Comment: Found the rpm for mcrypt from WHM and installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the RPM for mcrypt and also installed libmcrypt from WHM on my VPS.